# How to insert a username if it doesn't already exist with a postgresql POOL query

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, heroku

I am making a game and I recently added a server database score saver but I can't figure out how to insert a username only if it doesn't already exist here is the following query:

```
const addUser = (req, res) => {
    const {username, score} = req.body;
    pool.query(
        'INSERT INTO userlist (username, score) VALUES ($1, $2)',
        [username, score],
        (err) => {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.status(201).json({status: "success", message: "User added."});
        },
    );
}
```

I am guessing I'll have to change the query
also here is my **SQL** code for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE userlist(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    score VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to let the *database* validate the uniqueness of the username:

```
alter table userlist add constraint unq_userlist_usename unique(username);
```

Now if you attempt to insert a single row, then it will return an error if the row already exists.

If you don't want an error you can use an `on conflict` clause.  However, in this case, an exception seems useful to notify the user that `username` already exists.

Comment: should I put that in the query string?

Comment: @PugmanDude . . . No.  You add the constraint once and then the table makes it part of the table definition.

Comment: So I am using heroku I would just use that statement in the postgresql heroku panel

Comment: So I'm using heroku I would just alter the db's userlist table to add the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

use an if statement to identify if the username exist and then update it

```html
        if (Users::where('name', $request->user_name)->exists()) {
        return response()->json(['record exist']);
} else {
        $save = new Users;
        $save->name = $request->user_name;
        $save->save();
        return response()->json(['User saved successfully.']);
}
```

Comment: I don't get that I gonna need a different way

Comment: what i mean is check if $1 is already in your database and if it is you can run a function to just update $2